Firebase Extensions: delete user data in sub-collections
I don't know where to ask and I was not able to find that in documentation. I am using Delete User Data extension: https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/delete-user-data.
From the docs and everywhere they write an example for deleting from multiple collections like: users/{UID}, admins/{UID} etc. I am curious how can I delete this user by id from subcollections of other users. Here is the use case for two user IDs foo and bar:
User with id foo:
/users/foo/followers/bar
User with id bar:
/users/bar/following/foo
I want to delete user foo from the following sub-collection of user bar.
I've turned on recursive delete with depth 3. I've tried specifying collections like users/{otherUid}/followers/{UID} in the extension configuration - no luck.
I'd very like to hear input from the Firebase team here. Thanks in advance!
Example image (don't pay much attention to IDs themselves, its just a sample structure):
My expectations are that if I delete user with id 424596510 (from Firebase Authentication) - it will be deleted the highlighted users followers collection.



From the docs and everywhere they write an example for deleting from multiple collections like users/{UID}, admins/{UID}.

Yes, if the user data exists in multiple collections, for example, users and admins, and each document ID is represented by the UID of the user that comes from the Authentication process, then you can add multiple paths separated by commas, users/{UID},admins/{UID}.
This basically means that you can delete the data that is associated with a user from multiple Firestore collections.

I am curious how can I delete this user by ID from subcollections of other users.

This Firebase Extension allows you to delete the data that is associated with a user and additional data that exists within other sub-collections. To achieve this, you have set the "Enable autodiscovery" to "Yes" which:

Works by automatically traversing the database to find collections and documents that should be deleted according to your configuration.

So in your case, the 3) b. it will apply, which:

Finally, for each document: a. If the current search depth (see below) is less than or equal to the configured search depth, the process will be repeated for all of the current document’s sub-collections.

So this Firebase Extension will help you delete user documents that exist in sub-collections and not only in root collections. It will also delete documents that have a field set to the UID.
What will no do:

It will NOT automatically delete UIDs stored in arrays or maps, and it will not search for data keyed by user ID stored in deeply nested subcollections past the depth specified above.


Right, so I cannot use any wildcards? Something like users/*/followers/{UID} What's the point in Enable auto discovery then? I thought that this is smart enough to look for and traverse sub-collections as well based on the UID.

@OlegNovosad Oh, you're right. Some changes have been made lately. So please check my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Thanks for the update answer. Well, you basically quoted the documentation by parts :) I don't understand what is wrong here then with my expectations to the extension? I have user with ID added as document in other collection, so it should be deleted with automatic discovery, but it is not. I've updated the question with example image of structure.

So you say that when you delete the 424596510 user, it is only deleted from the users collection but not from the followers sub-collection, even if you have enabled automatic discovery?

Yes, absolutely correct. It is not deleted from the followers collection. That's why I put this question here to get clarity on what I am missing

If you followed the exact steps that are described in the docs and you see that the Extension doesn't work the way you expect, and since this Extension is created by Firebase, you can either dig into the open-source code to see what exactly doesn't work or you can you reach out to Firebase Support.

Hey Oleg. Did my answer/comments help? Can I help you with other information?
